# Pinterest API Stopped Working

Tags: pinterest

We've been using the Pinterest API for the last few months to create Pins using image URLs and links (so it will Pin an image with a link). In the last couple of weeks our script has stopped working.

In the API explorer, we get the following error:

root:{} 1 item
error:Sorry, something went wrong at our end. Please try again.

Here's the URL that gives the error: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?access_token=AV2x8IKqgFOZNDmlFJSgfT9uyy8LFQaZPGHWp6NDfJQRcoBAgQAAAAA&fields=id%2Clink%2Curl%2Cnote

What's the problem here?

Update: it works when we change the image URL from https://s3.envato.com/files/230512024/PaletteKnife_PreviewImage.jpg to e.g. http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%203/doctype-hi-res.jpg

So the issue would seem to be with the image file?

Comment: Could it be an API limit on the image height? I could not find any specifications on their API, though...

Comment: Maybe. I just tried with a much shorter image (https://s3.envato.com/files/241699493/23%20-%20Communication%20General.jpg ) and it worked OK.